# How can I split string like key and value using scala in efficient way:

Tags: scala

How can I split string like key and value using scala in efficient way:

I would like to split below emp string into key value pair.

```
var emp = "Map(employees -> [{"id":"100","name":"Alex","state":"MA"},{"id":"101","name":"Agni","state":"CA"},{"id":"102","name":"Sharo","state":"TX"}])"
```

**Need to parse like below :**

```
key: employees 
value : [{"id":"100","name":"Alex","state":"MA"},{"id":"101","name":"Agni","state":"CA"},{"id":"102","name":"Sharo","state":"TX"}]
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, `emp` looks like it's already in the format you're asking for.

Comment: Hi Musa, I think you mistakenly have put the Map you want to obtain instead of the string you want to parse. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Im new to scala. String looks like below. Here Map is just word. 

"Map(employees -> [{"id":"100","name":"Alex","state":"MA"},{"id":"101","name":"Agni","state":"CA"},{"id":"102","name":"Sharo","state":"TX"}])"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code parse the string into 2 others (key and value):

```
object Parser extends App {
  
    val emp = "Map(employees -> {\"id\":\"100\",\"name\":\"Alex\",\"state\":\"MA\"},{\"id\":\"101\",\"name\":\"Agni\",\"state\":\"CA\"},{\"id\":\"102\",\"name\":\"Sharo\",\"state\":\"TX\"}])"
    
    val key = emp.substring(emp.indexOf("(") + 1, emp.indexOf(" -> "))
    val value = emp.substring(emp.indexOf(" -> ") + 4, emp.indexOf(")"))

    println(s"key: $key");
    println(s"value: $value")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Decly ... How can I convert into Map(String,String) in single line ?

Comment: You can do something like Map(emp.substring(emp.indexOf("(") + 1, emp.indexOf(" -> ")) -> emp.substring(emp.indexOf(" -> ") + 4, emp.indexOf(")")))